# Changing title using filter not working with argument

Tags: filters, wp-title

I'm trying to change my custom page's title and I'm able to do this with this function:

```
add_filter('the_title','change_title');
function change_title($data){
    global $post;
    return 'Page ID ' . $post->ID;
}
```

and I'm calling the filter:
    `apply_filters('the_title', $response->data->name);`
This works fine but when I try to use the `$data` the page title returning to default name. I mean if change the filter to this:

```
add_filter('the_title','change_title');
function change_title($data){
    global $post;
    return 'Page ID ' . $data;
}
```

the title returning to default title. Why I can't set a dynamic title? Also I'm pretty sure that I'm passing a string. (BTW I'm using Hestia theme)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a higher priority to your filter as the 3rd parameter of the hook:

```
/**
 * Modify the data
 * 
 * @param String $data
 *
 * @return String $data
 */
function change_title( $data ) {

    global $post;

    return 'Page ID ' . $data;

}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title', 15 );
```

The default priority is 10 so it could be that a later filter is overwriting what you have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but didn't worked. I got the same result without any errors

Comment: Where is the apply filter in comparison to where you're adding the filter hook? Is this in a plugin or theme?